# What is the specific name of this output?

Tags: python, function, higher-order-functions

I have made a function named 'function' as below.

```
>>> def function():
        return 'hello world'

>>> function
<function function at 0x7fac99db3048> #this is the output
```

What is this output exactly? It's specific name? And it's significance?
**I know it gives info about memory location. But I need more information about this output.**

Do the higher-order function return similar data while they are returning function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python function is an object and thus when you call `function` it returns you the memory address. The higher-order functions behave the same way. However there some differences:

```
def a():
    print("Hello, World!")

def b():
    return a

>>> a
<function a at 0x7f8bd15ce668>
>>> b
<function b at 0x7f8bd15ce6e0>

c = b

>>>c
<function b at 0x7f8bd15ce6e0>

c = b()
<function a at 0x7f8bd15ce668>
```

Note what the function `c` returns in different situations.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call the function, you need to call it with `()`. Without that you are seeing *reference to the `function` function* stored at `0x7fac99db3048`. You may also store it in another variable as:

```
>>> my_new = function  # store function object in different variable

>>> function
<function function at 0x10502bc80>
#                      ^ memory address of my system

>>> my_new
<function function at 0x10502bc80>
#                      ^ same as above

>>> my_new()    # performs same task
'hello world'
```

Let's see the content displayed for another function with name other than `function`:

```
>>> def hello_world():
...     print 'hello world'
...
>>> hello_world
#          v   Name of function
<function hello_world at 0x105027758>
# ^ says object of type 'function'|^- memory address of function
# (for eg: for class says 'class')|
```

Comment: That wasn't their question